# how can I dynamically create a new table (php) using data from a data base?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-tables

first time asking so please be nice :)... im trying to dynamically create a new table, based on content bringed from my db. The table should have 3 columns, each with its own header (first case: "plants", second: "users" third:"email") and as many rows as the data bringed from the db. Also every data redirects to another php link. Can you please help me?

This is a kind of graphic of what the page should look like:

[Example of the table im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c68Cf.png)

here is my code:

```
<?php
    $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","pablokvitca","") or   
        die("No se pudo conectar: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("gaea");
    $searched=$_GET['search'];
    $sql1= "SELECT * FROM  Plantas WHERE Nombre LIKE '%$searched%'";
    $sql2= "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username LIKE '%$searched%'";
    $sql3= "SELECT * FROM  Usuarios WHERE email LIKE '%$searched%'";

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);

    $e1 = "";
    $e2 = "";
    $e3 = "";

    $e1.='<table align="center" align="top">';
    //$e1.='<th>Plantas</th>';
    //$e2.='<th>Usuarios</th>';
    //$e3.='<th>Mails</th>';
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { //plants
        $e1 .= '<tr  align=left>';
        $pln = $row1['Nombre'];
        $idp = $row1['idPlanta'];
        $e1 .= '<td>';
        $e1 .= "<div style=color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;>";
        $e1 .= '<p> <a href="newPlanta.php?pltID='.$idp.'&viewer=true">Planta:'.$pln.'</a></p>';

        $e1 .= "</div>";
        $e1 .= '</td>';
        $e1 .= '</tr>';
    }
    echo $e1;
     //$e1.='</tr>';
    //echo $e1;
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { //user
        $e2 .= '<tr align=left>';
        $usu = $row2['username'];
        $e2 .= '<td>';
        $e2 .= "<div style=color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;>";
        $e2 .= '<p> <a href="perfil.php?id='.$usu.'">Usuario:'.$usu.'</a></p>';
        $e2 .= "</div>";
        $e2 .= '</td>';
        $e2 .= '</tr>';

    }
    echo $e2;
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { //email
        $ml = $row3['username'];
        $e3 .= '<tr align=left>';
        $e3 .= '<td>';
        $e3 .= "<div style=color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;>";
        $e3 .= '<p> <a href="perfil.php?id='.$ml.'">Email:'. $row3['email'].'</a></p>';
        $e3 .= "</div>";
        $e3 .= '</td>';
        $e3 .= '</tr>';
    }
        echo $e3;
     $e3.='</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection. You should be using PDO or mysqli with bound parameters.

Comment: If your tables all have the same structure, you should use the same table and add another column that would distinguish them. So if I understand you correctly, you would add a "plant" type, a "user" type and an "email" type. It is almost never necessary to dynamically add tables to the database.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the help, but maybe i didnt express myself correctly, i am not trying to add tables to the database, im triying to dynamically create a table (in the web page) based on data extracted from de database

Comment: Yeah, that totally was not clear. What's wrong with what you're doing now?

Comment: You're making one row per database record now. That's what `<tr></tr>` will do. If you want one column per database record, you'll probably want to load the results into an array and then output it. Also, `<nbsp>` is not an element!

Comment: The problem with what im doing now is that it doesnt do what i want, it only creates a table with one column filled with all the data from de db(when it should create 3 columns and fill each  row with data from the db)... what i thought about doing is to try to create a <tr> that fills with the content (everytime the while "refresh" itself it should fill again with the new content)from  $e1,$e2,$e3 (wich also uses <td>) but i cant find the way to use these variables since they are in three differents whiles (i also tried to  make only one while but i couldnt)

Comment: @miken32 im not trying to create one column per database record, im trying to create 3 columns (1 per while) and fill each column with the data from the db

Comment: @miken32 (Check the picture i just posted so that you can understand how the page should look like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I must admit, I do not understand *why* you want to arrange this table this way.  However, I cannot resist the challenge!

I took all the data and built an array using the same table structure you wanted.   Then once the array is finished, we can run a foreach loop to build the table.

I have not tested this because I don't have your database to run off of.  In my head, it works though.

```
<?php
  // Build an array holding all of the data from each table
  $rowNum = 0; // Start the count

  while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { //plants
    $data[$rowNum]['col1']['Nombre'] = $row1['Nombre'];
    $data[$rowNum]['col1']['idPlanta'] = $row1['idPlanta'];
    $rowNum++;
  }

  $rowNum = 0; // Restart the row count
  while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { //user
    $data[$rowNum]['col2'] = $row2['username'];
    $rowNum++;
  }

  $rowNum = 0; // Restart the row count
  while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { //email
    $data[$rowNum]['col3']['username'] = $row3['username'];
    $data[$rowNum]['col3']['email'] = $row3['email'];
    $rowNum++;
  }

?>

<table align="center" align="top">
  <tr>
    <th>Plants</th>
    <th>Users</th>
    <th>Emails</th>
  </tr>
<?php
  // Run a foreach on the array to build out the table:
  foreach($data as $key => $row){?>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php 
        if(is_array($row['col1'])){
          echo '<div style="color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;">';
          echo '<p> <a href="newPlanta.php?pltID='.$row['col1']['idPlanta'].'&viewer=true">Planta:'.$row['col1']['Nombre'].'</a></p>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
      ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php 
        if($row['col2']){
          echo '<div style="color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;">';
          echo '<p> <a href="perfil.php?id='.$row['col2'].'">Usuario:'.$row['col2'].'</a></p>';
          echo '</div>';         
        }
      ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php 
        if(is_array($row['col3'])){
          echo '<div style="color:black;margin-left:50px;font-size:25px;">';
          echo '<p> <a href="perfil.php?id='.$row['col3']['username'].'">Usuario:'.$row['col3']['email'].'</a></p>';
          echo '</div>';        
        }
      ?>
    </td>    
  </tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: hey @AlanQuandt thanks for the help, your code almost does what i need, but there are two problem: first (and more important) is that it only shows one result from each column (when it should be able to show as much results as the DB brings) second: the headers don't align with the results.

Comment: @KevinDaich I will try and mimic you database and give it a try.  I wrote that above blindly.

Comment: thank you SO MUCH. I have to finish a hole proyect, including this, for monday and i couldn't really figure it out by myself how to do this part, so again, thank you very much for the collaboration. Looking forward to see if you can help me.

Comment: Try it now...  I forgot to increment the $rowNum and mistakenly used the term $index after I decided to change it to $rowNum.  This should work better.